How to bit-shift with a multi line macro
I'm trying to write a macro that will take a one of four pre-defined alarm values and bit shift them to one of the upper 4 bytes. The idea is that the upper 4 bits of an 8bit value will be reserved for alarms, and the lower 4 for some other values to reduce data packet size when transmitting OTA.
Say in the below, I want alarm 1, 3, 6, and 8 to be moved to from
[ALARM_9][ALARM_8][ALARM_7][ALARM_6][ALARM_5][ALARM_4][ALARM_3][ALARM_2][ALARM_1][ALARM_0]
to
[ALARM_6][ALARM_1][ALARM_3][ALARM_8][][][][].
#define ALARM_0      0x00
#define ALARM_1      0x01
#define ALARM_2      0x02
#define ALARM_4      0x03
#define ALARM_3      0x04
#define ALARM_5      0x05
#define ALARM_6      0x06
#define ALARM_7      0x07
#define ALARM_8      0x08
#define ALARM_9      0x09


#define ACTIVE_ALARM_BITS(a) ( 
    if(a == ALARM_0) a >> 4  \    // 0x07
    if(a == ALARM_1) a << 3  \    // 0x06
    if(a == ALARM_2) a << 3  \    // 0x05
    if(a == ALARM_3) a << 7  \    // 0x04
    // etc
)

The above keeps returning "expected identifier before if" errors during compile. What is the correct way to format this if macro?

First you miss a backslash. Then you try to put statements as expressions, and don't have the statement separator between them. Why use a macro? Why not use a function?

Macro or function, you don't need any if statements for this task.

The macro code is gibberish. It would be clearer if you used a switch statement (or an indexed lookup into a constant array of intended values). I cannot figure out why if (a == 0) a >> 4 is annotated // 0x07  or if (a == 1) a << 3 annotated // 0x06 etc.  Is the swapping of ALARM_3 and ALARM_4 intentional or a trap for future maintainers?

besides syntax errors there's bit-logic flaws, split it on subtasks to get it clear

I have no clue what is being asked here...

Note that \ merges two lines together, so there can't be a // comment after it or weird things will happen. Use /*  */ comments.

The question is not clear. I will illustrate a possible answer for this interpretation:

We have a bit-mask a with one bit for each of alarms 0 to 9 in bit positions indexed by ALARM_i.
We want to construct an eight-bit value with the bits for alarms 6, 1, 3, and 8 in bit positions 7, 6, 5, and 4.

This function does that:
static uint8_t PrepareAlarmBits(unsigned a)
{
    //  Get the four alarm bits we are interested in.
    unsigned a6 = a >> ALARM_6 & 1u;
    unsigned a1 = a >> ALARM_1 & 1u;
    unsigned a3 = a >> ALARM_3 & 1u;
    unsigned a8 = a >> ALARM_8 & 1u;

    //  Shift each bit to its destination position.
    a6 <<= 7;
    a1 <<= 6;
    a3 <<= 5;
    a8 <<= 4;

    //  Return the combined bits.
    return a6 | a1 | a3 | a8;
}

It could be reasonable to rely on the compiler to optimize that, so there might be no need to make it a macro. However, if we do want to make it a macro, we can first compact the function a bit:
static uint8_t PrepareAlarmBits(unsigned a)
{
    unsigned a6 = (a >> ALARM_6 & 1u) << 7;
    unsigned a1 = (a >> ALARM_1 & 1u) << 6;
    unsigned a3 = (a >> ALARM_3 & 1u) << 5;
    unsigned a8 = (a >> ALARM_8 & 1u) << 4;

    return a6 | a1 | a3 | a8;
}

and then:
static uint8_t PrepareAlarmBits(unsigned a)
{
    return
        (a >> ALARM_6 & 1u) << 7 |
        (a >> ALARM_1 & 1u) << 6 |
        (a >> ALARM_3 & 1u) << 5 |
        (a >> ALARM_8 & 1u) << 4;
}

and then:
#define PrepareAlarmBits(a)       \
    (((a) >> ALARM_6 & 1u) << 7 | \
     ((a) >> ALARM_1 & 1u) << 6 | \
     ((a) >> ALARM_3 & 1u) << 5 | \
     ((a) >> ALARM_8 & 1u) << 4)


Hi Eric, thank you for that. Apologies for the ambiguous question - I had been moving places all weekend and running on fumes with 2-3 hours of sleep trying to also get this project done. Your answer is more or less what I need and I can use that to build upon what I need. Thank you again.

I do not guess what those shifts do and I only focus on macros.

No comments and spaces after \
Your a << x is no-op. You have two versions:


First is changing the parameter
the second onre is giving the value without affecting the parameter

#define ACTIVE_ALARM_BITS(a) do{if((a) == ALARM_0) {a >>= 4;} \
    else if((a) == ALARM_1) {a <<= 3;}  \
    else if((a) == ALARM_2) {a <<= 3;}  \
    else if((a) == ALARM_3) {a <<= 7;}  \
    }while(0)
    // etc

#define IFTRUE(a, b, c, d) ((a) == (b)) ? ((a) c (d)) 

#define ACTIVE_ALARM_BITS1(a) \
(IFTRUE(a, ALARM_0, >>, 4) : \
IFTRUE(a, ALARM_1, <<, 3) : \
IFTRUE(a, ALARM_2, <<, 3) : \
IFTRUE(a, ALARM_3, <<, 7) : \
/* .... */ \
IFTRUE(a, ALARM_9, <<, 2) :  - 1)\


void foo(unsigned a)
{
    printf("a before:%d ", a);
    ACTIVE_ALARM_BITS(a);
    printf("a after:%d\n", a);
}

void bar(unsigned a)
{
    printf("a before:%d ", a);
    unsigned b = ACTIVE_ALARM_BITS1(a);
    printf("b after:%d a after:%d\n", b, a);
}



int main(void)
{
    foo(ALARM_1);
    bar(ALARM_1);
}

https://godbolt.org/z/n37P8snTh
